# Xamarin garba collection runs often

Tags: android, xamarin

My Xamarin app on Android creates approx. 30 new references every second (I guess one reference occupy approx. 100 bytes - but this is not important). I create these objects intentionally and they should live throughout the lifetime of the application.

I can see more frequently this in log output as my application runs for longer time:

```
04-11 16:46:22.658 D/Mono    (14892): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 424 objects 2303 colors 445 ignored 814 sccs 424 xref 150 cache 0/0 setup 0.16ms tarjan 2.39ms scc-setup 0.20ms gather-xref 0.06ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.31ms
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 49.28ms
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 27.89ms, stw 29.64ms los size: 2048K in use: 467K
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 3936K in use: 2558K
```

After an hour my application runs the frequency is 1 per second.

The consequence is I can see lags in my application (as the GC takes several tens of miliseconds).

Is there anything I can do with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using some of the other GCs and GC options available? [Link here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#GC_Bridge_Options) to the GC options available and if you continue to read past that section, they go on to talk about ways to help the GC process, ways to debug issues, and at the very bottom offer a few more configurations. I won't pretend to know much about it but some simple testing may help you identify the optimal configuration for your app.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all GC types (tarjan, new, old), also tried MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=new,nursery-size=16m,soft-heap-limit=256m. With no success.

Answer (score 2):

using

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

In the manifest on the application tag tells the system that your app needs extra RAM(aka "heap"). The garbage collection is run because you are using a lot of memory - and because the max memory is limited by the system you need to request extra memory. YOu can't declare that your app needs x MB, the system gives you RAM automatically - declaring largeHeap ensures that your app gets enough memory to handle all your objects. And it is automatically scaled. One of my apps crashed because it was allocated 10 MB or so of ram (and that is a lot based on the default of my device). After I declared largeHeap, it uses about 30 MB of ram(on average) and doesn't crash. If it needs more, Android allocates more after a garbage collection event

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help neither. I think my app doesn't consume a lot of RAM (the objects I mentioned above are relatively small - tens or hundreds of bytes).

Comment: 30 * 100 = 3000. You add 3000 bytes per second. After one hour, you have added 10.8 megabytes. If you add largeHeap, you will get enough ram (say you get 14-16) MB, meaning you reduce the garbage events

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" did not help my situation either.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the ListView CachingStrategy option set to `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` causing the same GC issues as described on android only in debug mode.

Removing this and using the default solved the GC problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue running Android Background services. It was solved by making sure I kept a reference to the service in another class. I would try making sure a reference to the class/objects being freed exits. The GC can't collect if the app still has a reference to the memory. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using FFImage and was calling `ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache();` too frequenty. Make sure you aren't calling it explicitly, let android do it automatically on low memory situations on `OnTrimMemory` override.